# Unable to install TFlearn

Tags: tflearn

I am trying to install tflearn using source by using command:

```
python setup.py install
```

Even after the successful installation. I am unable to import it. I can't install it using pip because of some restrictions. My tensorflow  version is 1.8.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing setup. I copy-pasted the files that were present in tflearn-master to this folder:

C:\Users\vic\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

Now tflearn is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think better way to install any scientific package in python is to use Conda.
Installation Conda:

```
https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html
```

After installation:

```
conda install -c derickl tflearn
```

Or use:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

Comment: Can't use pip/conda install commands due to company restrictions.

Comment: Try this: python setup.py install --user